# Build LLVM from Rust for machine type wasm32

Tags: rust, llvm, emscripten

I'm trying to build a hobby project where I build a Rust file to WebAssembly. I want to pass more options to emscripten then Rustc and cargo seem to allow me (like MINIMAL_RUNTIME, ENVIRONMENT and INVOKE_RUN).

I had the 'brilliant' idea of compiling Rust to llvm, then feeding that llvm file to emscripten so that I can use the compiler options. However, when I try to build the WebAssembly, I get the error "machine type must be wasm32".

This is the file I'm trying to build:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello World!");
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to build it:

```
rustc --emit=llvm-ir test.rs
emcc test.ll -O0 -s WASM=1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? (Or another way I can achieve my goal?)

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I needed to add a target option:

```
rustc --emit=llvm-ir --target wasm32-unknown-unknown test.rs
emcc test.ll -O0 -s WASM=1 -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0
```

Of course, this leaves me with "Unknown symbol" errors now... -sigh-

EDIT: Actually, what I should be doing is using the -C flag on rustc to directly pass paramaters to emcc, which is what I wanted to do in the first place:

```
rustc --target wasm32-unknown-unknown -C link-arg="-s MINIMAL_RUNTIME=1" -C link-arg="-s INVOKE_RUN=0" test.rs
```

Comment: rustc --crate-type=lib --emit=llvm-bc --target wasm32-unknown-emscripten test.rs -o testw.bc
emcc testw.bc -O0 -s WASM=1 -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 -o test.wasm

Comment: ...is how you avoid the Unknown symbol warning/error